# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL from makefile and run migration scripts

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, makefile, database-migration

I'm currently working on a simple project which is accessing the `Github API`.
`PostgreSQL` is used only to get more familiar with it.

I encountered a problem when trying to run the migration scripts from a makefile. This issue does only occur when I'm using make, by applying the migration scripts manually works fine.

The idea is to do this when running "make install":

1. `Start the PostgreSQL container`
2. `Run migration scripts`
3. `Stop & remove the container`

```
include ./config/dbConfig.env

all: install
.PHONY: all

install :
    #runns all migration script. To run a specific migration version build more targets.
    @echo "Get latest https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate image"
    docker pull migrate/migrate
    
    @echo "Starting postgreSQL database"
    docker run -t -d \
    --name dev \
    --env-file $(shell pwd)/config/dbConfig.env \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    -v $(shell pwd)/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
    
    @echo "Wait for database"
    sleep 5

    @echo "Sun migration scripts"
    docker run \
    -v $(shell pwd)/migrations:/migrations \
    --network host migrate/migrate \
    -path=/migrations/ \
    -database "postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@localhost:5432/?sslmode=disable" up
    # for specific migration: ....432/?sslmode=disable" up {{add integer migration number}}

    @echo "Stop and remove PostgreSQL container"
    docker stop `docker ps -aqf "name=dev"`
    docker rm `docker ps -aqf "name=dev"`
```

You can also find the latest version is on the branch "develop" or this specific commit [here](https://github.com/filikos/github-repo-crawler/commit/638ead5d1e164b6dd573361d7d71fd2e6bbe68d8)

Error:

```
error: read tcp [::1]:34022->[::1]:5432: read: connection reset by peer
```

Why am I unable to connect to the server from the makefile but if I run the same procedure manually it works? Do you maybe have any ideas about why the behavior is not consistent?

Comment: Please provide more context around the error message.  Exactly which command in the list above gives you that error?  Please show the actual command line.

Comment: Are you sure that your 5 second sleep is enough to let PostgreSQL start up? Or whether it started at all? It seems that nobody is listening on port 5432 when the migration wants to connect.

Comment: @MadScientist `docker run \
 -v $(shell pwd)/migrations:/migrations \
 --network host migrate/migrate \
 -path=/migrations/ \
 -database "postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@localhost:5432/?sslmode=disable" up` This command is throwing the error.

Comment: @raspy I just tested the same setup on my linux system. It works without any error. On my mac maschine it seems that 5 seconds are not enough but 10 for example work.

Comment: @raspy A better approach would be to wait if the container is running. Therefore I tried ` until [ "`docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} dev`"=="true" ]; do
  sleep 0.1;
 done;` not sure what causes the `/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file` because im only using tabs instead of spaces and also there is no wrong placed spaces. You got an idea?

Comment: Please update the question with output of the command: it's impossible to format things properly in comments.  What you quoted is the makefile command but you should include the command that make actually invoked: the output it prints.